# How are discord super reactions implemented in react

Tags: android, ios, react-native, web, animation

How can animations like the [Discord super reactions](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/12102061808663-Reactions-and-Super-Reactions-FAQ) be implemented for web app, say in react, or for mobile apps say for IOS apps? I am wondering if anyone knows js library or framework that offers similar animation capabilities?